# How to understand a comparison in Huff's How to Lie with Statistics

Tags: statistics

In the book *How to Lie with Statistics* (pp. 56-57), Huff (1954) gave an example of comparing IQ scores to illustrate the significance of probable errors.

> [...] So Peter's indicated IQ might be more fully expressed as $98 \pm 3$ and Linda's as $101 \pm 3$.
>
> This says that there is no more than an even chance that Peter's IQ falls anywhere between $95$ and $101$; it is just as likely that it is above or below that figure.  Similarly Linda's has no better than a fifty-fifty probability of being within the range of $98$ to $104$.  From this you can quickly see that there is one chance in four that Peter's IQ is really above $101$ and a similar chance that Linda's is below $98$.  Then Peter is not inferior but superior, and by a margin of
>   anywhere from three points up.

I do not see how "Peter is not inferior but superior, and by a margin of anywhere from three points up."  Can someone explain?

Comment: He means that, in the event that it turns out that Peter's IQ is higher than Linda's, Peter is superior to Linda.

Comment: @saulspatz: Thanks for your paraphrase.  I understand the sentence, but not the inference behind.  How come?

Comment: @reflectionist If we accept the premise that Peter's IQ exceeds 101 and that Linda's is less than 98, the statement that Peter's IQ exceeds Linda's by 3 points or more is obviously true. That's all the sentence is saying.

Comment: @SteveB: Oh, now I see what "then" means.  Thanks a lot.